# Missing tags in DevEco Studio, HarmonyOS

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos, deveco-studio

I am using DevEco Studio 2.1.0.501 IDE. I want to create a simple LITE watch application for smart device.

1, Is there any way to use more languages like java or kotlin (I don't really like JS)? I came from Android Studio.

2, I want to use this separator or divider tag : https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/design/des-guides/separator-0000001053499780 but it looks like the IDE can't recognize that. Or this : https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/design/des-guides/scrollbars-0000001053181026

Also a lot other tags can't be recognized. Why? This document is outdated or the IDE is outdated?

Thanks,
Leslie

Comment: hi@lacas, Could you kindly help us with some information to locate this issue? 
1. Version of the SDK that you are using
2. Compileversion used by the current project.
3. Version of the plug-in you are building.

Comment: hi @shirley DevEco Studio 2.1.0.501, SDK API 5, Js 2.1.1.21 I am in Hungary so the site doesn't allow to download newer version

Comment: @shirley I just downloaded the Deveco 2.1.501 from the Huawei site and created a Lite project with js. Nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, Lite version does not support Java or Kotlin.

For question 2, please refer to this [document](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/lite-wearable-common-attributes-0000001222151179) for information on supported tags. It is true that not all HMTL tags are supported or recognized by the DevEco Studio/HarmonyOS projects